# What's the reason getting OOM when openning hundreds TEXT tables using HSQLDB CREATE TEXT TABLE

Tags: hsqldb

Running with `-Xmx1024m`, trying to open 100 CSV files as `CREATE TEXT TABLE`, `SET TABLE SOURCE`. Somewhere in the middle getting OOM.
Tried to reduce cache_scale to 1. Works better, but still OOM at some point.
What's the reason?

I've found that memory is aggressivelly used to allocate lot of `org.hsqldb.PointerNode` instances. Any reason to avoid that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TEXT tables are special tables that use a CSV (comma separated value) or similar file as their data source. These tables can be used just like any SQL table both for querying and writing data.

Although the data is stored in the CSV file, indexes and pointers to rows of data are stored in memory. By default there is a single index on each table that also supports the table's PRIMARY KEY if there is one. UNIQUE or FOREIGN KEY constraints on these tables are backed up by in-memory indexes.

The `cache_scale` (with HSQLDB 1.8.x) is used to control the amount of row data that is cached in memory at any time. A smaller value reduces the memory used for caching data but does not change the memory needed for the indexes.

Comment: Fred. How to avoid creation of that index? I really don't need it as I'm selecting row by row form tables...

Comment: Some form of index is necessary even if the data is selected row by row. We will improve TEXT table support in future versions and perhaps support disk base indexes. For your usage, you can reduce the number of concurrently loaded tables with `SET TABLE T SOURCE OFF` and `SET TABLE T SOURCE ON`